# Add image in Two - Column CV

Tags: two-column, cv

Please find the format of two-column CV in 
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv

I wish to add my photograph within the yellow box. But when I am adding it, the yellow color is overlapping my picture. I dont wish to change the width of text in yellow box, just the size of box or something else which can help me to aciieve my aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the command `\personal` is used in that class to define the orange box with personal infos:

```
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    \Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}
```

To get the image on the right of that box, we need to add an column and use `\multirow` to add the image over all rows in the table:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % <====================================
\usepackage{multirow} % <====================================
% Renders a personal data box:
\renewcommand\personal[4][]{% <==============================
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|Xc} % <====================================
    \Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip & \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-10x16}}\\ % <====================================
    \Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip & \\ % <====================================
    \Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4} &  % <====================================
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1} &} % <====================================
    \end{tabularx}}}
```

Please see that I added the name of the image directly (not using an parameter for it and that I played with the used `width=1.5cm` to keep the image in the orange box. Depending on your image you have to play with `width` too.

Please see the complete mwe

```
\documentclass{tccv}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
% Renders a personal data box:
\renewcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|Xc}
    \Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip & \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-10x16}}\\
    \Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip & \\
    \Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4} & 
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1} &}
    \end{tabularx}}}


\begin{document}

\part{Nicola Fontana}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

Software development for the industrial automation sector: configuration
front-end in C with interface based on \href{http://www.gtk.org/}{GTK+},
web applications and sites on LAMP platforms grounded on the
\href{http://www.silverstripe.org/}{SilverStripe} framework,
supervisor programs in LabVIEW and remote system in
\href{http://www.lua.org/}{Lua} on GNU/Linux systems.

\item{January 2002 -- June 2004}
     {TEMA s.r.l., Travagliato}
     {PLC Omron development}

Development and testing of automatic and semiautomatic machines for
ribbon winding on spools and rolls (safety belts, hook-and-loop tapes,
elastic ribbon and bindings). Designing of electrical schematics on
2D cad and user manuals drafting.

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.

\item{September 1996 -- September 1998}
     {Elettronica EFFE-GI s.n.c., Cazzago}
     {PC and PLC Hitachi development}

Development of automatic machines in general, here included the design
of electrical, pneumatic and hydraulic schematics on 2D cad and the PLC
programming. Implementation of configuration and logging front-end using
RS232 serial communications between PC and PLC-based transfer machines
in BASIC, Pascal and C.

\item{January 1994 -- June 1996}
     {Seven Diesel s.p.a., Rovato}
     {Engineering department director}

Planning of nozzles for diesel engines and organization of production.
Upgraded the management software by implementing a system for data
handling and automatic drawing generation (in DXF) developed on the
SuperBase 95 RAD tool.

\end{eventlist}

\personal
    [www.entidi.com]
    {viale Conciliazione, 13\newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
    {+39 (30) 6862332}
    {ntd@entidi.it}

\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Public projects}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2012}
     {ntdisp (\href{http://ntdisp.entidi.com/}{ntdisp.entidi.com})}
     {Embedded devices programmer}

\item{2007}
     {tip (\href{http://tip.entidi.com/}{tip.entidi.com})}
     {PHP framework based on PEAR}

\item{2006}
     {adg (\href{http://adg.entidi.com/}{adg.entidi.com})}
     {Automatic drawing generation}

\item{2006}
     {gtk2panel (\href{http://gtk2panel.entidi.com/}{gtk2panel.entidi.com})}
     {Top panel menu in GTK+2}

\item{2004}
     {ntd (\href{http://ntd.entidi.com/}{ntd.entidi.com})}
     {General purpose libraries}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Italian}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Oral: fair -- Written: good}
\item{Spanish}{Oral: good}
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {C, PHP, HTML, CSS, autotools, git, gcc, GTK+, GObject, shell,
      MS-DOS, Linux, ladder, G-Code}

\item{Intermediate}
     {Lua, \LaTeX, MySQL, VBA, cuBasic, pascal, subversion, LabVIEW}

\item{Basic level}
     {Windows, FreeBSD, OpenIndiana, Postgres}

\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Comment: It served my purpose almost, I am trying that image fills the yellow portion left in height. How to do that?

Comment: @user688435 play with the value of `\includegraphics` option `width=1.5cm` ... At last it depends on the number of lines in the orange box and your used image ...

Answer (score 0):

This adds an image to the `\personal` macro:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.9\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%  
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}\\
    \Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Nicola Fontana}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

Software development for the industrial automation sector: configuration
front-end in C with interface based on \href{http://www.gtk.org/}{GTK+},
web applications and sites on LAMP platforms grounded on the
\href{http://www.silverstripe.org/}{SilverStripe} framework,
supervisor programs in LabVIEW and remote system in
\href{http://www.lua.org/}{Lua} on GNU/Linux systems.

\item{January 2002 -- June 2004}
     {TEMA s.r.l., Travagliato}
     {PLC Omron development}

Development and testing of automatic and semiautomatic machines for
ribbon winding on spools and rolls (safety belts, hook-and-loop tapes,
elastic ribbon and bindings). Designing of electrical schematics on
2D cad and user manuals drafting.

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.

\item{September 1996 -- September 1998}
     {Elettronica EFFE-GI s.n.c., Cazzago}
     {PC and PLC Hitachi development}

Development of automatic machines in general, here included the design
of electrical, pneumatic and hydraulic schematics on 2D cad and the PLC
programming. Implementation of configuration and logging front-end using
RS232 serial communications between PC and PLC-based transfer machines
in BASIC, Pascal and C.

\item{January 1994 -- June 1996}
     {Seven Diesel s.p.a., Rovato}
     {Engineering department director}

Planning of nozzles for diesel engines and organization of production.
Upgraded the management software by implementing a system for data
handling and automatic drawing generation (in DXF) developed on the
SuperBase 95 RAD tool.

\end{eventlist}

\personal
    [www.entidi.com]
    {viale Conciliazione, 13\newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
    {+39 (30) 6862332}
    {ntd@entidi.it}

\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Public projects}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2012}
     {ntdisp (\href{http://ntdisp.entidi.com/}{ntdisp.entidi.com})}
     {Embedded devices programmer}

\item{2007}
     {tip (\href{http://tip.entidi.com/}{tip.entidi.com})}
     {PHP framework based on PEAR}

\item{2006}
     {adg (\href{http://adg.entidi.com/}{adg.entidi.com})}
     {Automatic drawing generation}

\item{2006}
     {gtk2panel (\href{http://gtk2panel.entidi.com/}{gtk2panel.entidi.com})}
     {Top panel menu in GTK+2}

\item{2004}
     {ntd (\href{http://ntd.entidi.com/}{ntd.entidi.com})}
     {General purpose libraries}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Italian}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Oral: fair -- Written: good}
\item{Spanish}{Oral: good}
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {C, PHP, HTML, CSS, autotools, git, gcc, GTK+, GObject, shell,
      MS-DOS, Linux, ladder, G-Code}

\item{Intermediate}
     {Lua, \LaTeX, MySQL, VBA, cuBasic, pascal, subversion, LabVIEW}

\item{Basic level}
     {Windows, FreeBSD, OpenIndiana, Postgres}

\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need it on the right side (adjecent) of address "vial- conc..." not in the above portion